# How do I create a node.js application with SSL on AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, paypal, amazon-elb

I need to create a node.js application on AWS with SSL to support PayPal payment. I am not sure how to configure and what to configure. I currently have the application running but purely on HTTP (not HTTPS). Please provide options on the best ways to configure.
I am on a Window Server - there are two parts to this
1) How do I configure AWS?
2) How do I configure Node?

Answer (score 0):

Simply generate your SSL certificate and set it in nginx conf

Example :
Your application is running on localhost:3000
Your domain is test.com

Add a configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-enables/ for example conf.conf containing the following

```
#redirect http to https
server {
        server_name test.com;
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server{

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name            test.com;
    ssl_certificate        YOUR_CRT_FILE.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    YOUR_CRT_KEY.key;
    ssl_protocols          TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers            HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

nginx will now manage your https request

Test the configuration with the following cmd:

```
$ sudo nginx -t
```

if success reload nginx :

```
$ sudo nginx -s reload
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have node running on an EC2 instance I would use an ELB with an SSL cert.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html

An ELB and a Amazon Cert Manger make this stupid easy.

Another option would be to use Elastic Beanstalk. Much more turn key and easy to setup.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html